# Crystal Reports 2016 Command Object error in where clause

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a command object in Crystal Reports 2016 retrieving data from SQL Server 2019.  I have tried using the IIF function and Case.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Material_Trans.Material_Trans_Date AS Mtd, Material_Trans.Job AS TmJb FROM 
PRODUCTION.dbo.Material_Trans Material_Trans WHERE  Case '{?IssueStock}' When 'Stock' Then 
Material_Trans.Tran_Type Like 'Transfer' And Material_Trans.Material_Trans_Date Between {? 
SDate} And {?EDate} Else Material_Trans.Tran_Type = 'Transfer' ORDER BY 
Material_Trans.Material_Trans_Date DESC
```

I receive a message that there is a syntax error at 'Like'.  When using the IIF function the error will occur at the same location.  I have tried using = instead of Like but receive the same error.

Comment: A command is send to the database, not interpreted by CR. So you should tag your question with the database you're using.

Comment: Why?  It works fine in sql server.  The problem is on the CR side.  Apparently CR does not just send the command to the database.

Comment: I doubt that this query works fine in sql server. At least there's an "end" missing after the "case" in the Where clause.